# Como Web Workers funciona no Chrome

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou utilizando um WebWorker e localmente ele não está funcionando e não estou conseguindo achar uma solução.

Criei um arquivo de teste para exemplificar aqui:

**WebWorker.js**

```
var i = 0;

function timedCount() {
    i = i + 1;
    postMessage(i);
    setTimeout("timedCount()",333);
}

timedCount();
```

**HTML Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <p>Count numbers: <output id="result"></output></p>
        <button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button> 
        <button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>

        <script>

        var w;

        function startWorker() {
            if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") { 
                if(typeof(w) == "undefined") { 
                    w = new Worker("WebWorker.js");
                } 
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...";
            }

            w.onmessage = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
                };
        }

        function stopWorker() { 
            w.terminate();
            w = undefined;
        }

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

O erro que está apresentando no Chrome é:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker'

Comment: Não devia ter uma tag `<script>` carregando o arquivo `webworker.js`?

Comment: Não Renan. É um arquivo JS externo. Mostrei apenas o conteúdo principal aí.

Answer (score 1):

Você provavelmente está abrindo o arquivo diretamente no browser, correto? O chrome não carrega workers a partir um arquivo local (protocolo `file://`).

Dentro da pasta onde está o seu `index.html` levante um servidor rodando:

`php -s localhost:3000`

E teste a página através deste endereço.